# Jquery Mobile inserting buttons trhough javascript loses Styles

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

So I am dynamically creating a list of button and then inserting them into a div in jquery mobile page. Problem is when they are inserted they are no longer styled with as they would be if I just manually entered them in the html. Here is the code for what I am doing:

```
function iabGetURLs(){
var allURLs = window.localStorage.getItem("iabURLs");
html = "";
tmpURLs = allURLs.split(",");
for(var z=0;z<tmpURLs.length;z++){
    var urlParts = tmpURLs[z].split("|");
    html += '<input type="button" rel="' + urlParts[0] + '" class="iabListButton_' + z + '" value="' + urlParts[1] + '" />';    
}
$(".iabList").html(html); //puts it in the div
```

Click function:

```
$("[class^=iabListButton_]").click(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $goURL = $this.attr('rel');
    startBrowser($goURL); 
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you dynamically add content you need to either call a `.button()` method on every button individually or call `trigger('create')` on a parent to enhance all newly added elements.

Try change

```
$(".iabList").html(html);
```

to

```
$(".iabList").html(html).trigger("create");
```

**UPDATE:** Since you inject button's markup for them in order to work you need to use event delegation to attach an event handler to the nearest static (not changing) parent element. In your case it seems to be `$(".iabList")`. That being said change

```
$("[class^=iabListButton_]").click(function(){
...
});
```

to

```
$(".iabList").on("click", "[class^=iabListButton_]", function(){
...
});
```

Read more **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

You might need to detach a handler with `.off()` first

```
$(".iabList").off("click", "[class^=iabListButton_]").on("click", "[class^=iabListButton_]", function(){
...
});
```

Comment: I should have know that. I had a simialr problem the other day. In this case when I called the trigger I had it on the wrong class. Talk about wasting time. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry I was wrong. Although it does add the style back. Now it doesnt call the click function.

Comment: @SeeleyBoothe Although it was not a part of your question show your click function. You most probably don't use event delegation.

Comment: Edited first post and added click function

Comment: And I hate to add another part, but any idea why the click would fire twice?

Comment: @SeeleyBoothe See an update. You might need to detach a handler before you attach it.

Comment: Yeah fought with this all weekend. Still fires twice. Can't think of what elese to do.